# Php conditional help needed

Tags: php, conditional-content

I am trying to add conditionals for authorship to show for posts on a specific  author id. Would appreciate if someone could give the following a quick look over

```
<?php if is_author ('2') AND ( is_single() ) {?>
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/**********"/>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: I was just after a quick code audit which has been taken care of, thanks anyway kaiser

Comment: The posted (and accepted) answer is in no way different to your questions code. `&&` and `AND` are ***exactly*** equal in that statement.

Comment: I use AND but when it comes to conditionals I only have XF as a reference, the response posted helped confirm I was on the correct track and it does differ from mine slightly, cheers for confirming that AND is acceptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is related to php
so you should post it in stackoverflow 
but as you are a new user .i would help you

```
<?php if (is_author('2') && (is_single()) ) { ?>
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/**********"/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and I will post appropriately next time